# How do I properly install Django?

Tags: python, django, installation

I'm trying to setup a Django project and am a bit stumped on this part of setting everything up.

I've ran `pip install django` and tried running django by doing

```
python
import django
```

but I immediately get a message `ImportError: no module named Django`

I've tried going to the folder `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages` but there is nothing in that folder. If I go to `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages`, all of my modules are there including django. Now should everything go in the site-packages folder? I'm really confused as to why django isn't running the way it should be. I tried reading the Django documentation but that assumes my installation correctly goes into `.../site-packages`

Comment: are you using `virtualenv`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip install Django`.

For some reason they used a capital 'D' in Django instead of the normal all lower case. Source:[Django Documentation](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/).

Also make sure that`/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages` is added to your `PATH`.

The normal behavior of `pip` is to install into the `site-packages` folder. Maybe try re-installing `pip`?

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a `virtualenv`, especially if you're going to be making several Django applications that have different requirements.  You also have to run `pip` with `sudo` so `sudo pip install django`.  To learn how to make a virtualenv: http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/ .

You can also check your `$PATH` variable to see if `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages` is there, if it's not you can add with by adding the following to your .bash_profile

```
PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages"
export PATH
```

Under `virtualenv`, you don't have to use `sudo pip`, instead cd (change directory) to your environment directory, and run `pip install django` and it will *only* install it for that project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using "Virtualenv", if not than you should think about using virtualenv. I suspect you are not using it and doing a system install of Django.

So make sure that Django is getting installed properly. May be that you dont have the user rights to make a system wide install, so try to do `sudo pip install django`.

Hope it works out for you, if not try to be more descriptive of your problem.